# Why $\log(1/8(6t+1))+C=\log(6t+1)+C$

Tags: integration

I'm going to fully embarrass myself on this post, but I'm preparing for prelims, and trying to get my calculus back up to speed, and I came across this issue.  In the attached image, the coefficient $\frac{1}{8}$ is removed right before the last step, and for the life of me I can't figure out why it's done.  The answer Wolfram got to is correct, but I have no idea why the $\frac{1}{8}$ is simply removed from the calculation.

Thank you so much for any clarity you can offer!

[image: Removal of coefficient during integration by substitution]

Comment: $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$. Wolfram is stripping off the $4/3\log(1/8)$ and absorbing it into the arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log(a\cdot b)=\log a+\log b$, hence $\log (1/8)$ is moved to the constant of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$. Hence 
$$\frac{4}{3}\log\left(\frac{1}{8}(6t+1)\right)+C=\frac{4}{3}\log(6t+1)+\frac{4}{3}\log\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)+C$$

Noting that $\frac{4}{3}\log\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)$ is just a constant, we have that  $\frac{4}{3}\log\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)+C$ can is an arbitrary constant, so we can just write

$$\frac{4}{3}\log\left(\frac{1}{8}(6t+1)\right)+C=\frac{4}{3}\log(6t+1)+C'$$
where $C'$ denotes an arbitrary constant.

It is worth noting that the answer 
$$\frac{4}{3}\log\left(\frac{1}{8}(6t+1)\right)+C$$
is correct, just as the answer 
$$\frac{4}{3}\log\left(\frac{1}{8}(6t+1)\right)+100000+C$$
is correct. It's just that we like the final form because it is simpler to write.